# How do I programmatically disable the maximum failed attempts for an #Android fingerprint authentication?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to be able to increase the number of maximum failed authentication attempts.  Currently the default is set to 5 failed attempts before the FingerprintService locks the user out and receives the message: "Too many  attempts.  Try again later."

Is there a way to programmatically remove the cap on the number of attempts and disable this message?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, it's defined in [Android 6.0 Compatibility Definition Document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) in Fingerprint Sensor section:

> MUST rate limit attempts for at least 30 seconds after 5 false trials
>   for fingerprint verification.

So each phone providers, with fingerprint sensor, must implements this specification to be compatible with Android specs (and allowed to install Google apps : GMail, Maps, Play,...).

Comment: @user6505061 Is it useful ?

Comment: I mean... can someone brute-force your fingerprint?

Comment: Brut-force no, but it could be attacked as this :https://www.ccc.de/en/updates/2013/ccc-breaks-apple-touchid

Comment: But the "5 tries lock" system doesn't prevent that ccc attack in any way... What's the point of it?

Comment: Have you read the post ? it's not brut force attack but create a fingerprint from a finger put on a glass for instance

Comment: Yes, I have read the post. My point is that the "5 tries lock" system for fingerprints is useless, it doesn't stop the fake fingerprint method.

Comment: The fake fingerprint may work 1rst time so issue is not about "5 tries lock" but in the availability to create a fake fingerprint which work with some sensor. There's no "perfect" security  system.

Answer (score 0):

No but You can add more and other figers not just the index one. What works for me is always wipe my finger or erase all the current ones and register again, also make sure to register other fingers at the same time because if one doesn't work the other ones will.i also register my left fingers on add more fingerprints.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35063275)